# C++ syntax I am not familiar with

Tags: c++

I see some C++ syntax I am not familiar with:

```
fftfilt *mark_filt;
.
.
.
mark_filt = new fftfilt( ... ); // I left out arguments for the constructor.
.
.
.
mark_filt = (fftfilt *)0;
.
```

I do not understand what (fftfilt *)0 means or does?
Perhaps someone who uses c++ all the time can explain this to me?

Thanks,
Howard

Comment: it's a pre-c++11 way of casting a null pointer to the correct type.

Comment: I wonder if it is the same thing as "mark_filt = NULL" ?

Comment: The cast is  not necessary in C++, but it is in C. You can simply say:  `mark_filt = 0;` - this used to be the preferred way of creating a null pointer, prior to C++11.

Comment: Start here: [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an old way to represent `NULL`, which is generally just a macro defined to be `0`. You should instead prefer

```
mark_filt = nullptr;
```

although I hope before then since there was a `new` someone called `delete mark_filt`

Comment: Yes, I see another functon which does a "delete mark_filt;"

Answer (score 0):

The first comment is correct; it's a pre C++ 11 way of explicitly casting a null pointer to the correct type.  And you are correct, it is equivalent to `mark_filt = NULL;`, sort of.

C++ performs implicit type promotion for various conversions, but these are limited. In the case of pointers, the pre C++ 11 way was to use `NULL` or `(pointer_type *)` cast.  `NULL` itself has an implementation-specific definition and is implemented in different ways in the standard C++ headers (stdlib, I believe).  Two common implementations of `NULL` are:

```
#define NULL 0
```

```
#define NULL ((void *)0)
```

The ramifications of these depend on compiler, but the second will fail if assigned to a non-pointer type.  It will be implicitly cast to the correct type as it is not specifying the record Type that it is pointing to (ie. `void` is essentially a null type, `void *` is a pointer to null type, or an *unspecified* type).

In C++ 11 and above, it is more common to use `mark_filt = nullptr`, but this code would compile.

The MSDN site has some good documentation on this (no plug intended):

- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/NULL
- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion